# Why is the scanner function not working?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

So this code takes the value of n and returns a list of divisors as well as the total number of divisors. If I remove the `Scanner` declaration and its assignment to int n and simply give int n a value, the code runs perfectly.

However, as it is, it returns this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Program.main(Program.java:25)
```

I have no idea what the problem is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program{
    static int n;
    static int x = 1;
    static int [] arr = new int[n];
    static int q = 0;
    static int g = 0;
    static int p = 1;
    static int count;


    public static void main(String[] args){

         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         int n = scan.nextInt();

         while(x <= n){

            arr [q] = p; //assigns value to each array index
            g = n%arr[q]; // stores value of remainder
            q++; 
            p++;
            x++;
            if (g == 0){ //counts and displays each time remainder  = 0
                count++;
                System.out.println(q);
            }

        }

        System.out.println(count + " Divisors");


}
}
```

Comment: observe your while condition, `x <= n`. remember that array index starts from 0 not 1.

Comment: You declare your int[] `arr` as having length `n`. However, you don't give `n` a value, so by default it is 0. Therefore, `arr` has length 0, so no wonder you are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exceptions.

Comment: suppose you have not  assigned a value to `static int n` and hence the `arr` size if 0 by default. Also there is a local variable `int n` other than the `static`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of `arr` is declared when `n` still holds no value(before the size is inputted). Do this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {
    static int n;
    static int x = 1;
    static int [] arr; //no size set
    //...
    //Other variables
    //...

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        arr = new int[n]; //Now the size is set to the inputted number.
        while(x <= n) {
            //...
            //Other code to find divisors
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

You need to name the size of `arr` *after* you input the `n`, otherwise the size is set to `0`, causing the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

This line:

```
arr[q] = p;
```

Is what actually caused the error. `arr[q]` couldn't hold a value, because there *was* no `arr[q]`. the array had no size, so it couldn't hold any members.

Comment: Oh... yes! I missed that part, you got it, it's a plus one

Comment: Makes sense. For some reason I was thinking that giving n a value somehow retroactively adjusted the array's length. Easy fix.

Comment: @user8360486 Yep. No problem

Answer (score 1):

```
static int n;
...
static int [] arr = new int[n];
```

You do not give `n` a value, so it defaults to 0. Therefore, you initialize `arr` as an array of length 0. That is why you get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`. It's because your array is size 0, so even index 0 is out of bounds of the array.

If you don't know `n` until you read from the Scanner you should change your code to:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int n = scan.nextInt();
     int [] arr = new int[n];
 ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your while condition from

```
while(x <= n)
```

to

```
while(x < n)
```

`<` means strict less than, so you start from 1, and not get the out of bounds

Edit:

Also as @CodingNinja said, you have to change the and define a int value to the size of the array, by default is 0:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     static int n;
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int n = scan.nextInt();


     static int [] arr = new int[n];

     while(x <= n){

        arr [q] = p; //assigns value to each array index
        g = n%arr[q]; // stores value of remainder
        q++; 
        p++;
        x++;
        if (g == 0){ //counts and displays each time remainder  = 0
            count++;
            System.out.println(q);
        }

    }

    System.out.println(count + " Divisors");


  }
```

Comment: @CodingNinja yes... how could I missed that? thanks so much

Comment: There you go, +1 for you